# Is there any way to install Python 3.9 on Centos 7 without using source code (tar.gz/tgz)?

Tags: python, centos7, python-3.9

Is there any alternative way to install Python 3.9 in Centos 7 instead of using source code (tar.gz/tgz)?

We are running Python scripts so expecting Python to be installed at OS level and don’t want to create any virtual environment.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding virtual environments. They are created using a Python that's already installed on the computer, so they aren't really relevant to your question.

Comment: Have you looked into [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) ? It installs from source, but manages everything itself.